# Changing the text on a jquery dialog button affects button height

Tags: jquery, button, dialog

I have a jquery modal dialog, and I am trying to change the text shown on a button after it is clicked. So, for example, the Send button gets changed to 'Sending...' and is disabled when it is clicked.

This all works fine, with one problem: the button loses all of its internal padding, and the button border wraps right around the text.

```
$('#email-dialog').dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    height: 'auto',
    width: 'auto',
    modal: true,
    buttons: {
        "Send": function() {
            $(".ui-dialog-buttonpane button:contains('Send')").button("disable");
            $(".ui-dialog-buttonpane button:contains('Send')").button().html('Sending...');

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: post_path,
                data: form_data,
                dataType: 'JSON',
                success: function(data) {
                    if (data.success) {
                        $("#email-dialog").dialog("close");
                    } else {
                        updateErrors(data.errors);
                        $(".ui-dialog-buttonpane button:contains('Sending...')").button("enable");
                        $(".ui-dialog-buttonpane button:contains('Sending...')").button().text('Send');
                    }
                },
                error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    alert('Error: ' + textStatus + ' ' + errorThrown);
                    $(".ui-dialog-buttonpane button:contains('Sending...')").button("enable");
                    $(".ui-dialog-buttonpane button:contains('Sending...')").button().text('Send');
                }
            });

        },
        Cancel: function() {
            $(this).dialog("close");
        }
    },
    close: function() {
        allFields.val("").removeClass("ui-state-error");
    }
});
```

I have tried with both the html() and text() methods. Am I missing something really obvious here?

Comment: Clearly whatever is happening happens in the call to `.button()`.  If I had to guess, that function removes and recreates the element, wiping out all styles in the process.

Comment: I think you want to change the [`label` property](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Button#option-label) on the button.

Comment: @mmcnickle You are right! How obvious. Please add it as an answer so that I can give you credit.

Comment: Oops, on further testing, it doesnt work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a look at the html at the button actually renders you'll notice that there is a `<span>` inside the `<button>` tag.

```
<button type="button" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only" role="button" aria-disabled="false">
    <span class="ui-button-text">Send</span>
</button>
```

So to get your code to work, you should probably do something like:

```
$(".ui-dialog-buttonpane button:contains('Send') span").text('Sending...');
```

**EDIT:** As per mmcnickle's comment, it looks like the jQuery UI Button has a label property that you can use. E.g.

```
$(".ui-dialog-buttonpane button:contains('Send')").button('option', 'label', 'Sending...');
```

[jsFiddle of it in action](http://jsfiddle.net/cvallance/JeBsQ/)

[jQuery UI Button Label Documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Button#option-label)

Comment: Yeah, I would say setting `label` would be the better approach, as you don't need to rely on the underlying markup, which may change in future jQuery UI versions.

Answer (score 3):

You change the text in a jQuery UI button, by changing the `label` option:

```
$('#button_id').button('option', 'label', 'New button text here')
```